# Adding vectors in Matlab

Tags: matlab, addition

I'm newbie in Matlab. I have 4 different vectors and I need to add them like this:

mod1+lan1= x1
mod2+lan2= x2

But as you can see in the code the numbers are different.

```
mod1= [413 443 467 487  531 547 648 666 677 747 859 867 905 936 1388 1631 2121];
mod2= [mout8_c mout9_c mout3_c mout10_c mout11_c mout12_c mout1_c mout13_c mout14_c mout15_c mout2_c mout16_c mout17_c mout18_c mout26_c mout6_c mout7_c]

lan1= [485 560 660 815 1650 2215];
lan2=[out1_c out2_c out3_c out4_c out5_c out7_c]
```

So, what I've done for the x1 is:

```
x=[mod1 lan1];
x1= sort(x);
```

But the problem is on y because I need that the positions would be the same (like for example, on the position 413=mout8_c) but the numbers are totally diferents.

To sum up (maybe it's better if you look at this graph). I have that points and I need to add them in the order of each one.
http://img88.imageshack.us/img88/4604/16620372.jpg

Thanks a lot in advance and greetings,

Emma

Comment: I don't see how this can be possible as mod1 and lan1 have different number of dimensions.

Comment: Thanks bdecaf! I don't know also how to do it!

Comment: So what would you expect as result?

Comment: http://img88.imageshack.us/img88/4604/16620372.jpg I expect to have one vector called x, and another called y, like in the graph of the image.

Comment: your graph has 3d data.  It really is not clear what you are trying to do. What *are* `mod2` and `lan2`?  Labels?

Comment: Can you please be more specific about the desired output? The graph is not that clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't add those vectors, you concatenate them. You can not add vectors of different size.

When you use sort on x, you can obtain the permutation vector. Get it and use it on y instead of sorting it separately

```
temp = [mod1 lan1];
[x1, perm] = sort(temp);
temp = [mod2 lan2];
x2 = temp(perm);
```

I used x2 instead of y - this is what you used in the begining of your question.

Answer (score 0):

At the end, I used that code:

```
mod1= [413 443 467 487  531 547 648 666 677 747 859 867 905 936 1388 1631 2121]';
lan1= [485 560 660 815 1650 2215]';
mod2 = { 'mout8_c'    'mout9_c'    'mout3_c'    'mout10_c'    'mout11_c'    'mout12_c' 'mout1_c'    'mout13_c'    'mout14_c'    'mout15_c' 'mout2_c'    'mout16_c'    'mout17_c'    'mout18_c'    'mout26_c'    'mout6_c'    'mout7_c'}';
lan2 = {'out1_c'    'out2_c'    'out3_c'    'out4_c'    'out5_c'    'out7_c'}';
[x1,i1] = sort([mod1;lan1]);
y = [mod2;lan2];
out = y(i1);
```

Thank you a lot to everyone!